# AWS DMS for Cross-Account Migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-rds

I want to migrate the MySQL RDS database from one account to another,but there is no provision to select the database from another account.

And I need to keep track of all changes in the current RDS even after migrating. That's why we have chosen the MDS service.

Ex: I have an existing database in account A and a new database in account B. I need continuous migration of data from account A to account B.

Right now I am trying to achieve it was with the AWS database migration service. I couldn't find the way to select the database from another account. Please suggest if there is any better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just made these DMS cross-account works.

First, you should create the source and target endpoint both on your Target account.

For your question, you said you couldn't select the source database (which stays on your source account) on your Target account, because you `shouldn't` choose `Select RDS DB instance`,  instead, you should give the information at `Endpoint configuration`.

At `Endpoint configuration`, provide the `endpoint identifier`, and choose `Provide access information manually`,  on the Server name section, give the source database hostname, which you can find at your source database stay in your source account in the `connectivity & security` Section.

For the target endpoint, you can simply select the database from your target account.

Make sure you can test both the source and target endpoint connection successfully at the console.

Also, create `Replication instances` and `Database migration tasks` all at the Target account.

I hope it helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

You can establish network between these 2 accounts(e.g vpc peering) and then use the database endpoint in the target of DMS.

Comment: I have done VPC peering from the Source account and created DMS in the target Account. But the database is  not appearing dropdown while creating the endpoint